# Errno 10061 : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ( client - server )

Tags: python, sockets

I have a problem with these client and server codes, I keep getting the **[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

I'm running the server on a virtual machine with Windows XP SP3 and the client on Windows 7 64bit, my python version is 2.7.3. What I want to know is how should I edit the code to use the client and server on different networks! Thanks!

**server :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = '0.0.0.0' # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.


print 'Server started!'
print 'Waiting for clients...'

s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr
while True:
  msg = c.recv(1024)
  print addr, ' >> ', msg
  msg = raw_input('SERVER >> ')
  c.send(msg);
  #c.close()                # Close the connection
```

**client :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

print 'Connecting to ', host, port
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
  msg = raw_input('CLIENT >> ')
  s.send(msg)
  msg = s.recv(1024)
  print 'SERVER >> ', msg
#s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

PS : code is from internet.

Comment: _actively refused it_ implies that the server machine's firewall blocked the connection, probably unrelated to code.

Comment: firewall is off :/ still getting error

Comment: How is your VM guest connected to the network? Via NAT + Port forward or by bridge mode?

Comment: It's via Via NAT + Port forward !

Answer (score 50):

10061 is WSAECONNREFUSED, 'connection refused', which means there was nothing listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

There was a firewall product around the year 2000 that issued refusals instead of ignoring incoming connections to blocked ports, but this was quickly recognised as an information leak to attackers and corrected or withdrawn.

Comment: @BenjaminEcker I see no rewrite, just an arbitrary change, and no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: This error can also occur when the server socket is overloaded and the backlog queue is full.  Readers can learn more about socket backlog from the `listen()` Linux man page.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: `actively refused` sounds like somewhat deeper technical trouble, but...

...actually, this response (and also specifically `errno:10061`) is also given, if one calls the bin/mongo executable [and the mongodb service is simply not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno10061) on the target machine. This even applies to local machine instances (all happening on localhost).

➪ **Always rule out for this trivial possibility first**, i.e. simply by using the command line client to access your db.

[See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno1006)

Comment: "Actively refused" means that a TCP RST was issued, which *only* occurs if nothing is listening at the port. There is no 'deeper technical trouble'.

Answer (score 4):

So I was facing the same issue,
and the solution that worked for me was...

I am assuming your server and client program are written in python.

1. First, open one python shell
2. open and run the Server program first
3. then open another different python shell
4. open and run the Client program here
5. done !!

Answer (score 3):

Using the examples from: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/socketserver.html
I determined that I needed to set the HOST port to the machine I had the server program running on.   So TCPServer on 192.168.0.1 HOST = TCPServer IP 192.168.0.1 then I had to set the TCPClient side to point to the TCPServer IP. So the TCPClient HOST value = 192.168.0.1 - Sorry, that's the best I can describe it.

Comment: In other words you had the target IP address wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship between error and firewall.

first, run server program,
then run client program in another shell of python

and it will work

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me but how to start a different python idle shell that is by just right-clicking on the idle symbol on the taskbar then click on idle3.8 then it opened a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

instead of localhost of '0.0.0.0', use local network address as host in case of both - the server and the client - code.

host = '192.168.12.12'
port = 12345

use this host address when binding and connecting to the socket.

server.bind((host, port))
client.connect((host, port))

this change solved the issue for me.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with binding the listening socket to 0.0.0. Using the local IP address doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the same IP and Port number in both client and server. 
Try, in client to use 
    TCP_IP = 'write the ip number here' 
    TCP_PORT = writ the port number here 
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

Comment: The solution is usually to use 0.0.0.0 in the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you have remote server installed on you machine. give server.py host as "localhost" and the port number.
then client side , you have to give local ip- 127.0.0.1 and port number.
then its works

Comment: The question is about 'different networks', and this answer won't even work on different hosts in the same network, let alone different networks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem when I was calling REST API using python library and what I found that my server was going into sleep mode which was leading to this. As soon as I logged in to the server via Remote Desktop Connection, my API call used to work.

Answer (score 0):

**This could be because of proxy or firewall. If it's proxy, then you need to specify proxy setting at entry point of your code or project.**

```
import os #for proxy

proxy = 'http://10.XX.XX.XX:8X8X' #your own proxy 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
#rest of code .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The below changes fixed my problem.
I struggled with the same error for a week. I would like to share with you all that the solution is simply `host = ''` in the server and the client `host = ip` of the server.

Comment: In the case that the server had been listening at say 127.0.0.1. It isn't a universal solution to all cases of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The first: Please make sure your port '12345' is opening and then
when you using a different network. You have to use the IP address in LAN. Don't use the 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.
The solution here is:
**In server**

```
host = '192.168.1.12' #Ip address in LAN network
```

**In client**

```
host = '27.32.123.32' # external IP Address
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: `host=''` is better in the server, i.e. listen at 0.0.0.0. That way it supports multuhoming, and survives reconfiguration.

Comment: Yup. If you using the domain then your solution is better. But I think in this case we should be using the static IP address

Comment: You think so why? It isn't better in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I had errors 10060 and 10061. The reason was in my antivirus(Eset Nod 32). Try to turn off the Firewall of your antivirus as I did or just delete it for a time to test the program. If everything started to work properly, add that program to the exclusion or switch to another antivirus.
Also, try to change the 'host' variable to an empty string:

```
host = ''
```

And add socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM to the 's' variable:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the client and server are running on the same machine (as in running 2 programs), it's OK to config both IP address as `locahost`. However, if you are to run them on different machines (including VMs), you need to

1. Make sure they are on the same subnet (usually by `ping`ing each other)
2. The Server needs to **config the host IP as its IP address** (like `192.168.xxx.xxx` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`). You may find the IP address by running `ipconfig` on Windows or `ip a` on Unix-like server

This change worked for me with my Client on Windows and Server on Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other solutions will work if you want to run `server.py` and `client.py` on the same machine. I wanted to try and run it on two different machines (windows and raspberry pi), but on the same network.

For me, it was a matter of choosing the correct IP address. If my windows machine is the server, I used the IPV4 address of the windows machine. This can be found by running `ipconfig` in the command prompt and selecting the 192.168.X.X number. The raspberry client side bounded to the same address. If the raspberry pi is the server, then I would bind to the inet address. You can find this by running `ifconfig` in the terminal (again the 192.168.X.X).

Note though, the IP addresses are temporary. I believe if you want a more permanent set-up, the server IP address needs to be bound to the router's IP address, then port-forward to the server. That way, the client wouldn't even have to be on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to start your server( run server.py ) using Command prompt and after that you can easily run client.py because you need a server first which will host so that client.py could be run.

Answer (score -1):

the short term solution is to use the default iis host and port normally 120.0.0.1 and 80 respectively. However am still looking for a more versatile solution.

Comment: Given that OP is running in two machines, and this is a localhost solution, it's unlikely to work?

Comment: And given that localhost is 127.0.0.1, not 120.0.0.1, it won't even work in one host.

Answer (score -1):

When you run the code on windows machine, firewall prompts it to allow network access, allow the network access and it will work, if it does not prompts, go to firewall settings > allow an app through firewall and select your python.exe and allow network access.

Comment: A firewall will cause a connect timeout, not a connection refusal.

Answer (score -1):

I was doing this tutorial and they said that windows users will have a problem. They said that you can check the Windows Firewall to fix the problem. Let me show you a quick Google Search on how to change the windows firewall:

```
Go to Start and open Control Panel. Select System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall. Choose Turn Windows Firewall on or off. Select Turn on Windows Firewall for domain, private, and public network settings.
```

After that, your app should work. Also, in your client(not server side) the port should be `0.0.0.0` and in the server side, it should be `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: You say ‘port’ but you provide IP addresses, and you have them back to front. It won’t work this way.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because you're trying to make a request to a port that isn't in an active connection

Comment: A port that isn’t in LISTEN state.He is trying to *create* an active connection.