# I am trying to connect python and mysql and I am facing the following error:

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Source code:

```
import mysql.connector

from mysql.connector import errorcode
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',database='menagerie')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cnx.close()
```

The error I am facing:
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Comment: You are not passing any password?

Comment: Do you have installed mysql client ?

Comment: Please refer to below link and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993276/errno-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-re

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector
cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user="root",host="localhost",passwd="*******",database="menagerie")
```

The above code establishes the connection to MySql.

Comment: here host is an optional parameter but passwd is necessary to make connection.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Comment: ^ what do I do?

Comment: when I don't include passwd parameter then your code print "Something is wrong with your user name or password" but if I included passwd then it works fine.

Comment: If you have the same problem then try to install mysql client again.