# How can I resolve ConnectionRefusedError in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I'm trying to add the ability to reset a user's password with a password reset link with Flask but whenever I go to test out the functionality of this feature, I'm met with ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Here's the revelant snippets of code from my app.py and **init**.py. If this isn't enough to solve the problem, just let me know what else you need to see.

app.py

```
def send_reset_email(user):
token = user.get_reset_token()
msg = Message('Password Reset Request')
msg.sender = 'noreply@demo.com'
msg.recipients = [user.email]
msg.body = f"""
To reset your password, visit the following link: {url_for('reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}. 
If you did not make this request, then ignore this email and no changes will be made.
"""
mail.send(msg)


@app.route("/reset_password", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
form = RequestResetForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    send_reset_email(user)
    flash('An email has been set with instructions to reset your password.', 'info')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
return render_template('reset_request.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)
```

**init**.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()
mail.init_app(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'f645748071241866b90c405a391033ac'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND'] = False
```

Comment: Where, exactly, does this error appear?  In your browser?  In the terminal session where the flask server is running?  Somewhere else?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: always put code with correct indentations because indetation can change everything in Python code and we can't see what is real problem and what is only wrong copied code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errno 10061 : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ( client - server )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993276/errno-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-re)