# Selenium does not read links

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Well im using Selenium to scrape a web page, im at half of the proyect, i got all the links that i needed and save it in a dictionary like this:
`key={ "Page 1":[ 'https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com' ], "Page 2":[ 'https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com' ] }`

And i have a function that goes like this:

```
def scrape_info_for_pages(links_dict):
    all_info = {}
    service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service('C:/Users/...')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = False
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    
    try:
        for key, links in links_dict.items():
            info_for_key = []
            for url in links:
                result = scrape_info(driver, url)
                if result:
                    info_for_key.append(result)
            all_info[key] = info_for_key
    finally:
        driver.quit()
    return all_info
```

Anyways, i have tried my code of extraction ("scrape_info" function) in all of the links, and it works just fine. But at the time of running them with this code this is the error shown:

> Error processing https://example1/62330263/soledad: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=53650): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/95c46ef4fe35afc5fa2ed3bbfff6e0f4/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002541D536D10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
> Error processing https://example2/8503321/uribe: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=53650): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/95c46ef4fe35afc5fa2ed3bbfff6e0f4/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002541D53FDD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Have tried:

- Checked every link if its alive, all of them are
- Updated my chronium and my browser too
- Asked gpt xd

Im new at doing a giant proyect with Selenium so im open to all of your commentaries, thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

i see you are using your local machine to run the test. the issue you are having was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993276/errno-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-re). Im not sure what you plan to use this for but have you tried using live test like other websites? this way we can see if its your machines settings or the code. Let me know and i can try to help further!